# Binding a specific database field to a textbox directly in xaml/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I try to bind a specific database field to a textbox.
I'm working on a windows phone 8 application with the mvvm pattern.

The C# code works like this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = App.ViewModel.AllSettingsItems.First(x => x.ItemName == "Sample").Value;
this.txtSample.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

The table has 4 columns:
id(int), itemName(String), isActivated(bool), value(String)

Is there a way to do this directly in xaml?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whoever taught you how to wpf... kick them in the balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LstDB">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemName}" Margin="20,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

CS:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadData();
}

public void loadData()
{
    List<DB> list = new List<DB>();
    list.Add(new DB(1, "Item1", true, "10"));
    list.Add(new DB(2, "Item2", false, "20"));
    list.Add(new DB(3, "Item3", true, "30"));
    list.Add(new DB(4, "Item4", false, "40"));
    list.Add(new DB(5, "Item5", true, "50"));
    LstDB.ItemsSource = list;
}

public class DB
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public bool isActivated { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public DB()
    { }

    public DB(int id, string itemName, bool isActivated, string value)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.isActivated = isActivated;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

here, you just need to fetch data from Database and fill it list or any collection and provide itemsource to listbox or any control that you are binding.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! My problem is, that I don't want every database item in a listBox. I want to bind only one specific database field to a textBox.

Comment: check my answer i have done binding for id and itemName only not for all field. if you want so take property as you want to bind from DB Field. and get it from DB and set it as ItemsSource

Comment: Yes that's right. With your code I get a listBox with 5 entries of listItems, each with its ID and Name. To take your example, I want to bind the itemName of listItem 5 to a textbox.

Comment: for that You can have Query as your condition satisfies and get it from DB and bind it to ItemsSource. Whatever you want from DB just get it through Query or other manipulation and set it as ItemsSource

Comment: {Binding ITypedItWrong} but Visual Studio will still build without error. xaml sucks